# From declaring a dependency to actually using it with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-management

I'm quite familiar with Java Spring Framework and been developing a lot lately in Spring. Although I haven't been a part of setting up the Spring project myself and now im struggling with creating one myself.

I need to make a jdbc connection to my aws database, and I have a lot of great inspiration from different projects.

My question is; how do I go from declaring a dependency in my gradle.build file to actually using what I need.

I got this in my gradle.build (and some other stuff ofcourse)

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.4.3.RELEASE'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    classpath("mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.37")
}
}
```

I recently added the mysql-connetor to the class path in this gradle.build file AND:

```
dependencies {
compile('mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.37')
}
```

I added it as a dependency aswell. Now I write this in my application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Yet the line above is glowing red like it can't resolve the classpath?

EDIT:
Also, in my ApplicationConfiguration I would like to configure the DataSource, but even tho I add the dependencies:

```
compile('commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4')
compile('commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.2')
compile('commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10')
```

to my gradle.build, I'm not allowed to import import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource ??

I'm sure I'm missing something and feel quite stupid to be honest..

Comment: If you hover the "red glow" you should get a specific error message. It sounds like a problem with your Gradle file, and I recommend you post it in its entirety.

Comment: I just answered my own question. I did try to hover and It couldn't tell a specific error.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I figured it out. Guess what. I just had to click the 'Refresh Icon' in the Gradle window (in IntelliJ). Then it configured my project. I thought it did that when I was running 'build'.

Comment: You can also configure IntelliJ to do an auto-refresh on changes to the build file(s). The 'build' just builds using Gradle, the problem is that IntelliJ also needs to know which dependencies to use for auto-complete, syntax checking, etc. That is done by the refresh: IntelliJ will evaluate the gradle build result to determine the needed dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The only dependency you declared in the `build.gradle` file is to the Spring Boot gradle plugin. The main feature of this plugin is that it adds the `bootrun` task to your gradle build so that you can call `gradle bootrun` to start your application in development mode.

The Spring Boot Gradle plugin does **not** add Spring to your applications classpath, however!

Have a look at [Spring Initializr](http://start.spring.io/). There you can select some libraries you want to use and if you want to use Maven or Gradle. Initializr then creates a project with a `build.gradle` file for you which contains all needed dependencies.

Comment: As mentioned I haven't included the whole gradle.build file in my question, but thanks for your time. I make it work, I answered my own question below :-) !